# What's the most robust data medium for long-term cold (shelf, archival) storage?

Tags: archiving, usb-storage

I've been looking, for some time, for a class of storage medium that's particularly well-suited to archival storage (also known as 'cold' or 'shelf' storage; ie literally leaving it unconnected from electronics and sitting on a shelf for years at a time).

I use an NAS for primary storage but am looking for something else that I can use to *attempt to* preserve less valuable data (stuff like raw original takes and stock footage; a lot of my data storage is video).

I'm aware that depolarization and bit rot make flash media bad candidates for this use case.

As presumably most folks have, I've also come across the rather intriguing M-Disc technology in the course of researching this question (as well, of course, as LTO, which seems particularly well-suited to archival but which has major upfront investment costs and which is also susceptible to bit rot).

My question here is whether there are other technologies like the M-Disc on the market - perhaps those that offer even superior archiving and retention capabilities. Tangentially, I'd also be very interested to know what professionals, working in archive, use nowadays for this kind of use-case.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: The most robust long term storage media is either archival paper, or a live server with good raid disks replaced regularly.

Comment: John, the most robust long term storage media is stone. The reader technology (human eyes) will never be outdated. 
The disadvantage is the low data density.
I am not kidding - the German computer journal c't mentioned stone in a comparison table....

Comment: /me grins.   I was thinking of the 100 year old property deed and survey I have here.

Comment: not sure why it wasn't mentioned, but *M-Disc* is really promising. [Full China Lake Study](https://www.esystor.com/images/China_Lake_Full_Report.pdf) | [Summarized Version](https://www.verbatim.jp/download/products/mdisc/M-DISC_1sheet_ChinaLake_vF.pdf)